# Дата и время в С++

Tags: c++

Помогите получить в переменную число месяца. Вообще не представляю, как это сделать. Или может информацию по этой теме кто-нибудь имеет... Заранее, спасибо.

Comment: Какая платформа и компилятор?

Comment: windows xp
в visual studio 2008

Answer (score 5):

Используйте структуру [`SYSTEMTIME`](http://www.vsokovikov.narod.ru/New_MSDN_API/Time/str_systemtime.htm) в паре с функцией [`GetSystemTime()`](http://www.vsokovikov.narod.ru/New_MSDN_API/Time/fn_getsystemtime.htm):

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>

void main()
{
    SYSTEMTIME st;
    GetSystemTime(&st);
    std::cout << st.wDay; // Вывод дня месяца
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Если на чистом С++ и на Windows, то это делается через функцию [time](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/1f4c8f33.aspx) с последующим преобразованием результата в структуру [tm](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff567981) функцией [localtime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bf12f0hc.aspx).
Структура tm содержит требуемое поле:

```
struct tm {
  int tm_sec;
  int tm_min;
  int tm_hour;
  int tm_mday; ///< то что требуется
  int tm_mon;
  int tm_year;
  int tm_wday;
  int tm_yday;
  int tm_isdst;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 #include <atltime.h>
```

/////////Какой-то код

```
 int Month=CTime::GetMonth();
```

Примерно так...

Answer (score 0):

```
SYSTEMTIME st;
GetSystemTime(&st);
cout << to_string(st.wMinute) + "-"
    + to_string(st.wHour) + "."
    + to_string(st.wDay) + "."
    + to_string(st.wMonth) + "."
    + to_string(st.wYear) << endl;
```